# Qt signal emit in addressbook

Tags: qt, model-view-controller

I am learning the Model-View in Qt by the AddressBook example. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html 
     And I find something interesting. The code construct a TableModel class besed on QAbstractTableModel. In the override setData function, it emit the dataChanged signal. But, there is no signal emit in removeRows/insertRows. Then, how can these function update the View.

```
bool TableModel::removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index)
   {
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), position, position + rows - 1);

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        listOfPairs.removeAt(position);
    }

    endRemoveRows();
    return true;
   }

bool TableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole) {
        int row = index.row();

        QPair<QString, QString> p = listOfPairs.value(row);

        if (index.column() == 0)
            p.first = value.toString();
        else if (index.column() == 1)
            p.second = value.toString();
        else
            return false;

        listOfPairs.replace(row, p);
        emit(dataChanged(index, index));

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make note of function calls `beginRemoveRows()` and `endRemoveRows()` in the function `removeRows()` of your posted code.

The `beginRemoveRows()` function, **emits a signal** `rowsAboutToBeRemoved()`. This is how connected views can know about the deletion and the underlying connected views must handle before data is removed.

Look the note in below documentation:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginRemoveRows

Comment: Thank you very much. I just post a new question, can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375673/how-can-realize-my-own-memory-viewer-by-qt