# How can realize my own memory viewer by QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Recently I am writing a debugger for my own hardware. I want to add a memory viewer widget like the eclipse or qt creator or other IDE. However, I have no idea what kind of widget to use. For example, tableWidget, is there some setting to make it like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your question, do you want to get the first or second image?

Comment: two question: 1:  get the first image;  2 I have realized a window like second image, but I don't konw how to change the color of the text like second image

Comment: I recommend asking part by part as the questions are independent.

Comment: Because I can only ask one question in 90 min  ORZ

Comment: Ok, I will delete the second question.

Comment: Could you please indicate what the entry to the table is like

Comment: The table will show the Hex data in the memory.  The total memory is 2MB

Comment: You could provide the data by uploading it to dropbox, drive or similar and sharing the code to save time. ;P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155133/discussion-between-noodles-guo-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: @eyllanesc How does one get the Memory Browser window in QtCreator? I can't find anything in QtCreator version 4.15.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option is to create a custom widget because the task is private and none of the widgets are accommodated to the task.

For this we will inherit from QAbstractScrollArea, from this class inherit QTableView, QListView, QListWidget and QTableWidget. It is designed to display data within a QScrollArea.
In addition [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) of this class tells us how to create a custom class.

> When inheriting QAbstractScrollArea, you need to do the following:
>
> - Control the scroll bars by setting their range, value, page step, and
>   tracking their movements.
> - Draw the contents of the area in the
>   viewport according to the values of the scroll bars.
> - Handle events
>   received by the viewport in viewportEvent()
> - notably resize events.
>   Use viewport->update() to update the contents of the viewport instead
>   of update() as all painting operations take place on the viewport.

Taking that reference I created the following widget:

**memoryviewer.h**

```
#ifndef MEMORYVIEWER_H
#define MEMORYVIEWER_H

#include <QAbstractScrollArea>
#include <QBuffer>

class MemoryViewer : public QAbstractScrollArea
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MemoryViewer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MemoryViewer();

    void setData(const QByteArray &ba);
    bool setData(QIODevice &device);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);

private:
    void adjustContent();
    void init();

    int addressWidth();
    int hexWidth();
    int asciiWidth();

    QByteArray data(qint64 pos=0, qint64 count=-1);

    int nBlockAddress;
    int mBytesPerLine;

    int pxWidth;
    int pxHeight;

    qint64 startPos;
    qint64 endPos;

    int nRowsVisible;

    QBuffer buffer;
    QIODevice *ioDevice;
    qint64 size;

    QByteArray dataVisible;
    QByteArray dataHex;
};

#endif // MEMORYVIEWER_H
```

**memoryviewer.cpp**

```
#include "memoryviewer.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QScrollBar>

MemoryViewer::MemoryViewer(QWidget *parent):QAbstractScrollArea(parent)
{
    ioDevice = new QBuffer(this);
    init();
    connect(verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged, this, &MemoryViewer::adjustContent);
    connect(horizontalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged, this, &MemoryViewer::adjustContent);
}

MemoryViewer::~MemoryViewer()
{

}


void MemoryViewer::init()
{
    nBlockAddress = 2;
    mBytesPerLine = 16;

    pxWidth = fontMetrics().width(QChar('0'));
    pxHeight = fontMetrics().height();

}

int MemoryViewer::addressWidth()
{
    return  (nBlockAddress*4+ nBlockAddress -1)*pxWidth;
}

int MemoryViewer::hexWidth()
{
    return (mBytesPerLine*3+1)*pxWidth;
}

int MemoryViewer::asciiWidth()
{
    return (mBytesPerLine*2 +1)*pxWidth;
}

QByteArray MemoryViewer::data(qint64 pos, qint64 count)
{
    QByteArray buffer;

    if (pos >= size)
        return buffer;

    if (count < 0)
        count = size;
    else
        if ((pos + count) > size)
            count = size - pos;

    if(ioDevice->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        ioDevice->seek(pos);
        buffer = ioDevice->read(count);
        ioDevice->close();
    }
    return buffer;
}

void MemoryViewer::setData(const QByteArray &ba)
{
    buffer.setData(ba);
    setData(buffer);

}

bool MemoryViewer::setData(QIODevice &device)
{
    ioDevice = &device;
    bool ok = ioDevice->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    if(ok){
        size = ioDevice->size();
        ioDevice->close();
    }
    else{
        QBuffer *buf = new QBuffer(this);
        ioDevice = buf;
    }
    init();
    adjustContent();
    return ok;
}

void MemoryViewer::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
{
    adjustContent();
}


void MemoryViewer::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(viewport());

    int offsetX = horizontalScrollBar()->value();

    int y = pxHeight;
    QString address;

    painter.setPen(viewport()->palette().color(QPalette::WindowText));

    for(int row = 0; row <= dataVisible.size()/mBytesPerLine;  row++){
        QString str = QString("%1").arg(startPos + mBytesPerLine*row, nBlockAddress*4, 16, QChar('0')).toUpper();
        int i = 0;
        address = "";
        while(i < nBlockAddress){
            address += str.mid(i*4, 4) + ":";
            i++;
        }
        address.remove(address.size()-1, 1);

        painter.drawText(pxWidth/2 -offsetX , y, address);
        y+=pxHeight;
    }

    int x;
    int lx = addressWidth() +pxWidth;
    painter.drawLine(lx-offsetX, 0, lx-offsetX, height());
    lx += pxWidth/2;
    y = pxHeight;

    //hex data
    x = lx-offsetX+3*pxWidth;
    int w = 3*pxWidth;
    for(int col =0; col < mBytesPerLine/2; col++){
        painter.fillRect(x-pxWidth/2, 0, w, height(), viewport()->palette().color(QPalette::AlternateBase));
        x+= 6*pxWidth;
    }

    int bPos = 0;
    for(int row=0; row < nRowsVisible; row++){
        x = lx-offsetX;
        for(int col =0; (col < mBytesPerLine) && (bPos < dataHex.size()) ; col++){
            QString str = dataHex.mid(bPos*2,2).toUpper();
            painter.drawText(x, y, str);
            x += 3*pxWidth;
            bPos += 1;
        }
        y+= pxHeight;
    }

    lx = addressWidth() + hexWidth();
    painter.drawLine(lx-offsetX, 0, lx-offsetX, height());

    lx += pxWidth/2;

    bPos = 0;
    y = pxHeight ;
    int ch;
    for(int row=0; row < nRowsVisible; row++){
        x = lx-offsetX;
        for(int col =0; (col < mBytesPerLine) && (bPos < dataVisible.size()) ; col++){
            ch  = (uchar)dataVisible.at(bPos);
            if ( ch < 0x20 )
                ch = '.';
            painter.drawText(x, y, QChar(ch));
            x += 2*pxWidth;
            bPos += 1;
        }
        y+= pxHeight;
    }
}

void MemoryViewer::adjustContent()
{
    int w = addressWidth() + hexWidth() + asciiWidth();
    horizontalScrollBar()->setRange(0, w - viewport()->width());
    horizontalScrollBar()->setPageStep(viewport()->width());

    nRowsVisible = viewport()->height()/pxHeight;
    int val = verticalScrollBar()->value();
    startPos = (qint64)val*mBytesPerLine;
    endPos = startPos + nRowsVisible*mBytesPerLine -1;

    int lineCount = size/mBytesPerLine;
    verticalScrollBar()->setRange(0,  lineCount-nRowsVisible);
    verticalScrollBar()->setPageStep(nRowsVisible);

    if(endPos >= size){
        endPos = size-1;
    }
    dataVisible = data(startPos, endPos-startPos + mBytesPerLine +1);
    dataHex = dataVisible.toHex();
    viewport()->update();
}
```

An advantage of the implementation is that you do not have to load all the bytes directly since you can pass an object that inherits from `QIODevice` such as `QFile` and read the data when the view needs it by eliminating the memory overhead. In addition you can pass a `QByteArray`

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/46375673) you will find an example

[image]

Comment: I really really appreciate your help.  Beyond my words ~

Comment: I wish the link "In the following link you will find an example" wasn't broken.

Comment: https://github.com/dec1/stackoverflow-egs/blob/master/46375673-how-can-realize-my-own-memory-viewer-by-qt/MemoryViewer/main.cpp

Comment: @LUser try again: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/46375673