# How can I place Hex Data into a QT List Widget

Tags: c++, qt, hex, qlistwidget, hex-editors

simply put I am wanting to open a file and place hex data into a widget to make a hex editor.

I am confused because I am guessing I  will need a list widget which is what I have. What confuses me is that it appears that string data can enter this widget.

So I will need to open a file and divide the byte array out to fit into the widget and place those bytes into the list.

Here is the code that I currently have.  I want to improve this.

```
QString FileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open File", QDir::homePath());
    // DELETE cleanup later
    QFile File (FileName);

    if(!File.open(QFile::ReadWrite )){
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error!","File Not Opened!");
    }
    long fsize = File.size() / 10;  //amount of lines
    char* raw;
    uint length = 10;
    FileData = File.readAll();

    QDataStream reader(FileData.toHex());
    reader.readBytes(raw, length);
    QString str(raw);
    ui->DisassemblyListContent->addItem(str); // I expected at least hex bytes of the file here.
```

Desirable output would be that it places.

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
55 31 D2 89 E5 8B 45 08 56 8B 75 0C 53 8D 58 
FF 0F B6 0C 16 88 4C 13 01 83 C2 01 84 C9 75 
F1 5B 5E 5D C3
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375673/how-can-realize-my-own-memory-viewer-by-qt/46385049#46385049

Comment: Damn that is quite the answer. I am surprised I didn't find this earlier.